# Real part of analytic function is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function. Prove or disprove The real part of $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable or not.

I think the result is true.
Since $f$ is an entire function by Cauchy Riemann equations $f'(x,y)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)-iu_y(x,y)$.
Now since $f$ is an entire function by Cauchy Integral Formula for derivatives,  $f$ is many times differentiable and applying Cauchy Riemann equations repeatedly we can obtained the partial derivatives of all orders of $u(x,y)$ and they all are continuous. So $u$ is infinitely many times differentiable. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the right idea. A nice approach is by contradiction. If $Re(f)$ was not infinitely many times differentiable, then there is some $n$ such that $Re^{(n)}(f)$ is not differentiable, that is taking the partial by $x$ n times. But this means that the $n$th derivative of $f$ does not exist by the Cauchy Riemann equations, a contradiction since $f$ is entire hence infinitely differentiable.

Comment: How about the ( sort of ) converse: Is a Real analytic function the Real part of a Complex-Analytic function? It seems yes using Cauchy-Riemann, but I can't find a good argument.

Comment: @MSIS I’m pretty sure that the function needs to be harmonic. If the function is harmonic then definitely yes this is true. You can use the C-R equations to solve a sort of system of differential equations to find the function that makes the C-R equations work. This function is typically called the harmonic conjugate.

Comment: Thanks, @ R. Maresca. A kind of strange question: Is there a connection of some sort between Real-valued analytic functions of a Real variable and harmonic functions on the plane?

Comment: @MSIS So I think the closest thing is the close relationship between harmonic functions and complex analytic (holomorphic) functions. Being holomorphic; that is, satisfying the C-R equations is a stronger condition than being real analytic. For instance, holomorphic functions are linear over the complexes. While real analytic functions are linear over the reals, they may not be over $\mathbb{C}$. Since being holomorphic is a stronger condition, we need the extra condition that the real analytic function must satisfy Laplace's equation, hence be harmonic.

Comment: @MSIS But I'm really not an expert on complex analysis so I could be wrong there.