# Partial derivatives continuity and complex function differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

Suppose we know $\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x}$ is not continuous at $0$. Does this automatically imply $f(x+iy)$ is not differentiable at $0$? In order words is continuity of the first order partial derivatives of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ necessary in order for $f(x+iy)$ to be differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3878821/42969

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have never seen it stated but I think it is not a necessary condition. We know that a function is differentiable at $z=(x,y)$ iff there exists $f'(z)$ s.t$$f(z+H)-f(z)=f'(z)H+r(H), \lim_{|H|\rightarrow0}\frac{r(H)}{|H|}=0$$
with the last condition on $r$ being an equivalent condition to $f$ being differentiable at $z$. Let us look at only the real part of $r$, $r_1$, and the real part of $f$, $u(x,y)$, and the real part of the increment $H$, $h$. Then, consider the discontinuous partial derivative of $u$ at $(x,y)$, with respect to $x$. This means that $$\left|\frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}-\partial_x u(x,y)\right|\geq\delta_1$$for every $|h|<\epsilon$. Now, $$u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)-ah=r_1 \iff \frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)-ah}{h}=\frac{r_1}{h}$$
For $\frac{r_1}{h}$ to tend to zero as $h$ tends to zero, if for every$|h|<\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta_2$ such that
$$\left|\frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)-ah}{h}\right|\lt\delta_2 \\ \left|\frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)-ah}{h}\right|\le \left|\frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}-\partial_x u(x,y)\right|+\left|\partial_x u(x,y)-a\right|\geq\delta_1$$
I think that we have plenty of space for the discontinuity not to prevent the rest function from tending to zero, but I might be wrong.
**EDIT**:
In fact, Lima, Elon. E, on his book *Analysis Course II*,which is on Real Analysis, in this specific example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, remarks the following:

> $r(v)=f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b+k)-h\partial_xf+f(a,b+k)-f(a,b)-k\partial_y f$.
> By the Mean Value Theorem, there is a $\theta \in (0,1)$ s.t
> $$\frac{r(v)}{|v|}=[\partial_x f(a+\theta h,b+k)-\partial_x f(a,b)]\frac{h}{|v|}+\\+\left[\frac{f(a,b+k)-f(a,b)}{k}-\partial_y f\right]\frac{k}{|v|}$$
> Because $\frac{h}{|v|}$ and $\frac{k}{|v|}$ are bounded ($v=(h,k)$), we only need to assume continuity of the $x$ partial derivative, because the other term goes to zero in virtue of the definition of derivative.

This demonstrates that a function does not need to be $C^1$ to be differentiable. He even goes on to mention that in general a function of $n$ variables can have a minimum of $n-1$ continuous partial derivatives for it to be continuous. He further gives an example:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}} \hspace{2mm} \text{if} \hspace{2mm} x\neq 0 \hspace{2mm} \text{and} f(0)=0$
> A simple calculation shows that the derivative of this function exists at zero.

$\mathbb{C}$ must work the same way, as it is virtually indistinguishable from $\mathbb{R}^2$ whenever multiplication is not involved.

Comment: A function which is complex differentiable is then differentiable an infinite number of times. This is in stark contrast to real differentiable functions, so $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are definitely not indistinguishable. (They are indistinguishable as far as the topology goes, i.e. limits and continuity; but as soon as one speaks of derivatives, they are two completely different things). Since $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable it follows that the real part of $f$ is also infinitely many times differentiable and so in particular is in $C^1$.